# Facebook AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData is returning null in android

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin

I am using deferred deep link in my project, when I click the notification from facebook app it must navigate to my app and return the appLinkData. For the first time if I click the notification it navigates to my app and AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData function returns the appLinkData value and if I click next time  AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData is returning null value for appLinkData.

```
AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this) 
{ 
appLinkData ->
when{
appLinkData != null -> {
 // required code
}
}
}
```